# What is this perl script snippet doing?

Tags: regex, perl

I've been trying to search for resources on how to decode what is going on, here.  I've found several Perl "cheat sheets", but I'm having trouble finding definitions of the flags.  I've annotated what I think I know, and please correct me if I am mistaken.

I know that "$parm=~s/" makes the value of '$parm' equal to the return on the substitution regex(es).  Beyond this, I'm lost.  I THINK that the line "$parm=~s/+r/-s/;" removes carriage returns and white spaces, but I'm not 100% sure.  The + and - characters on that and all subsequent lines are throwing me.  I thought that the + character denoted "one or more", but the presence of the - in the second parameter makes me doubt that.

```
open(fitmp,"</tmp/new_parms$VAR.log"); <-- stores the file(?) in the file handler 'fitmp'
$parm=<fitmp>;  <-- stores the contents of the file in the variable "$parm"
chop($parm);  <-- stores the last line(character?) of the file in $parm
close(fitmp);  <-- closes the file
unlink("/tmp/new_parms$VAR.log";  <-- deletes the file
if($parm =~ /ABORT/){exit(1);}  <-- closes the program if there is a problem
$parm=~s/\+r/\-s/;
$parm=~s/\+m/\-m/;
$parm=~s/\+p/\-p/;
$parm=~s/\+cp/\-cp/;
```

Comment: The backslash character usually means an escape.  Surely it couldn't be this easy: Are the last, four lines really just subbing(in order) +r for -s, +m for -m, +p for -p, and +cp for -cp?  I'm going to feel like a moron if it's that simple...

Comment: It is that simple

Comment: Why don't you post the whole script. ?

Comment: You've got it backwards, though; in the last four lines, `+r` is being replaced with `-s`, `+m` is being replaced with `-m`, etc.

Comment: *"I know that "$parm=~s/" makes the value of '$parm' equal to the return on the substitution regex(es)."* Sorry, that's not correct: `$y =~ s/.../.../;` means "run this search/replace regex on `$y`, modifying `$y`." `$x = $y=~s///;` means "run the regex on the value of `$y`, modifying `$y`, and assign the return value of that operation, which is the number of substitutions made, to `$x`". `$x = $y=~s///r` (Perl >=5.14) means "run the regex on the value of `$y`, not modifying it, and assign the modified string to `$x`." [See also](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1215373).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 6):

You have the open right.

The next line depends on the value of `$/` which separates input lines for you. The default is a newline. If there is something like `local $/;` before this snippet, or `$/ = undef;`, then the lines won't be separated. Under default behavior, the second line will only read the first line of the log file for you. If `$/` is undefined, the entire file will be read in.

The third line with the [chop](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chop.html) removes the last character from `$parm`. ([chomp](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) is generally is a safer alternative that only removes the end if it is whatever `$/` is holding. There's likely no difference since your line should end with a single character `$/`, but you never know...)

The next few lines about closing and deleting the file are correct.

`/ABORT/` searches the `$parm` string for the pattern `"ABORT"`.

The substitutions at the end are all literal changes of `+r` to `-s` and conditional `+` to `-` (depending on the characters that follow) in the `$parm` string.

It might be helpful to print `$parm` along the way, so you can see what's happening.

Comment: Yep.  I feel stupid.  I was trying to make it too hard, when I should have just looked at what was there.  Thank you so much for your answer, Mr. Abercrombie.  It was most helpful.  I was scrambling around the net, looking for the definition of the "+/-cp" flag, when I should have just looked at the positioning of the escape characters.  Thank you, again.

Answer (score 5):

```
open(fitmp,"</tmp/new_parms$VAR.log"); <-- stores the file(?) in the file handler 'fitmp'
```

Opens the file and associates it with a filehandle (which means you can use the filehandle to access data from the file).

In old-style Perl, you'll often see code like this (although, it's generally considered good practice to use all upper-case letters when using this style of filehandle). And you should always check the value returned from `open()` and take appropriate action.

Newer Perl code will use a lexical variable for the filehandle and pass three arguments to `open()` (separating the file mode, `<`, from the name).

So I'd write this code as:

```
open(my $fitmp, '<', '/tmp/new_parms$VAR.log')
  or die "Can't open '/tmp/new_parms$VAR.log': $!";
```

Moving on...

```
$parm=<fitmp>;  <-- stores the contents of the file in the variable "$parm"
```

Stores the first line of data from the file in `$parm`. This data will include the newline character from the end of that first line.

```
chop($parm);  <-- stores the last line(character?) of the file in $parm
```

No. This removes the last character from the variable, `$parm`. I mentioned above that the data read from the file would include the newline character. This line of code removes it. Note, however, `chop()` is a slightly dangerous function to use (as it always removes the last character - even if it isn't a newline). Since Perl 5 was released (in 1994), we have the safer function `chomp()` which only removes newlines. You should use that instead.

```
close(fitmp);  <-- closes the file
unlink("/tmp/new_parms$VAR.log";  <-- deletes the file
```

Yes. Those two explanations are correct.

```
if($parm =~ /ABORT/){exit(1);}  <-- closes the program if there is a problem
```

More specifically, if the data you've read from the file contains the string 'ABORT', then exit the program.

```
$parm=~s/\+r/\-s/;
$parm=~s/\+m/\-m/;
$parm=~s/\+p/\-p/;
$parm=~s/\+cp/\-cp/;
```

You're right that `$var =~ s/PATTERN/STRING/` is doing a substitution on `$var`, but you're getting the details wrong. There's nothing about newlines or whitespace here.

The important thing to realise about these four lines of code is that the `+` and `-` characters are all preceded by a `\`. This has the effect of escaping them and means they match themselves, and don't have any of the special meaning that you mention in your question. It's also worth mentioning that there is no point in escaping the `-` characters in the replacement strings as the `-` has no special meaning in a string.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Cross.  That helps me a great deal.  I guess I was just overthinking it.